# Access Master page variables in child page in asp.net By using VB Language

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a Master page that Contain Following variable

```
Public cumRank, _
       peakRank, _
       allowTPT As Integer

Public form_no As Integer

Public cumPer, _
       cumPtl, _
       peakPer, _
       peakPtl As Single

Public std_name As String, _
       std_course As String, _
       std_batch As String
```

And I want to access the cumPer Variable in each child pages of it.

How can I Do?

Comment: maybe using sessions variables? https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-create-and-access-447ada98

Comment: and maybe I have a dirty mind... why do you name your variables that way? :p

Answer (score 0):

Use @MasterType directive in your content page. Then access your variables using Master property of page. Here is an example; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx